# Is it possible to get the ID of a processor/connector in apache NiFi using the rest API?

Tags: rest, apache-nifi

I'm exploring the rest API functionalities provided by NiFi. I have a question: can we get the ID of a component, be it a processor, processor group, controller services,etc., using `NiFi-API` by querying the component's name?

I tried `http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/flow/search-results?q=sample` I have a processor group named sample in my NiFi Flow.

[image]

And I have a `GetFile` processor named `sample get file` and I queried this: `http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/search-results/q='sample get file'`. None of them seem to work. The NiFi-API documentation wasn't quite helpful in these aspects. So guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De Santa,

If you wants to get id of the processor u have to know process group ID of the processor.

Here i have simple example in which gets the id of the processors in root.

http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/process-groups/root/processors

Above code works in nifi-0.6.1.

**EDIT1**

In NiFi-1.1.1

You have to use below rest api to collect processors

**Process group id:515eeb84-646b-4b33-eaf7-2028420a9fcb**

http://localhost:8089/nifi-api/process-groups/515eeb84-646b-4b33-eaf7-2028420a9fcb/processors

Above API collects number of processors in mentioned  Process group id.

[OR]

**Process group id:root**

http://localhost:8089/nifi-api/process-groups/root/processors

It collects the number of available processors in Root Canvas.

So if you know ID of the process group in which processor besides then easy to get processor ID.

Comment: Just tried that. It dint work. I also tried giving a processor group name instead of root and also tried the id of that processor group. None of them worked. By the way, my NiFi is a latest one and it uses NiFi-API 1.10.

Comment: Yep. Already got to know about the new changes in the documentation itself. Thought of updating it here but you posted it already. Thank you.

Comment: The UI uses the REST API exclusively to manage the data flow. If you open up the Dev Tools in your browser, you should be able to see all the requests in action.

Comment: excellent, in addition one can find process-groups inside process-groups and recursively find all processors: {{nifi_server_url}}/process-groups/root/process-groups